# Add button to textfield javafx

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-2

Simple question I hope. I am looking to add a button to a textfield in java. The textfield will be used to store a file location where a file will be saved / backed up.

Google hasn't been to helpful. Looking for something like this:

```
 +---------------------------------+
 |  F:\Backup.sql            | ... |
 +---------------------------------+
```

Assume there is a method to does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is an HBox where you can add the Textfield and the Button. Hope the following code snipped helps:

```
public class BackupUI extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setSpacing(5);

        final TextField locationTextField = new TextField("F:\\Backup.sql");
        Button saveButton = new Button("Save");

        saveButton.setOnAction(event -> save(locationTextField.getText()));

        hBox.getChildren().add(locationTextField);
        hBox.getChildren().add(saveButton);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(hBox));

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void save(String fileName) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Backup %s!", fileName));
    }
}
```

Comment: So there's no direct way of adding the button to the field. You've (basically) got to simulate it

Comment: I see no possibility to add the button directly to the TextField. You could try to develop an own component which extends TextField or HBox if you need.